# How to change height of a <br> tag in HTML?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to change height for a `<br>` tag.
This code written inside HTML tag which I have tried:

```
echo "<br style="padding-top:xxpx;">"
```

But, it doe not work:

```
          echo " $x" . " Degree"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";
          echo " $y" . " percent"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";
          echo " $a" . " percent"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";
          echo " $b" . " percent"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";
          echo " $c" . " percent"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";
          echo " $d" . " percent";
          header("Refresh:5");
//}else {
//echo "No Results";
//}

//$conn->close();

?>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you using `<br>` tag use <p> instead of that

Comment: learn some basic css

Comment: can't change p tag height too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing height of `<br>` is not appreciated. Place `<br>` element inside a `<p>` tag and apply line-height to the `<p>` element

```
echo '<p style="line-height:30px;margin:0px;"><br></p>
```

or simply the best try this

```
echo"<p style='margin:0px;'line-height:20px;>Your content Here</p>";
```

Comment: echo "<br style="line-height:100px;">";
doesn't work too

Answer (score 2):

This is a tiny CSS for answering your question:

```
br
{
   display: block;
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

But, I suggest you use `<div>` for formatting your layout, instead of using `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

As the 'margin' doesn't work in Chrome, that's why I used 'border' instead.

```
br {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; // Works in Chrome/Safari
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  br {
    margin-bottom: 10px; // As 'border-bottom' doesn't work in firefox and 'margin-bottom' doesn't work in Chrome.
  }
}
```